# NuGet Server - Access custom private NuGet gallery based on dynamic Feed URL

Tags: asp.net, nuget-package, nuget-server, nugetgallery

I need to provide **private NuGet** patch for the customers. We have more number of customers. We are in the position to provide different NuGet Patch to all needed customers. Now, I have followed below approach for provide NuGet patch

- provided **each NuGet feed link** for each customer and maintain **separate
  NuGet package folder** for each customer. But, we have maintained each
  **Web application** for each customer. This is very complex and it’s not
  possible achieve for more customers.
- This is my code block

**Web.Config**

```
 <appSettings>
<add key="requireApiKey" value="true" />
<add key="apiKey" value="" />
<add key="packagesPath" value="~/NugetPackages/customer1" />
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
<add key="" />
</appSettings>
```

I want to know other possibilities for to achieve this. My query is

For Example

- My Feed link is - http://mydomain/packages/c1 and
  http://mydomain/packages/c2 etc…
- C1 feed link is want to show only NuGet package which is in customer1
  package folder
- C2 feed link iswant to show only NuGet package which is in customer2
  package folder

  But We need to maintain one web application for achieve these.

Is this possible or not? Could you please share your ideas?

Thanks in Advance

Mathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted same query in NuGet GitHub, I got some response. In NuGet server not yet released dynamic Feed URL feature, this is in development stage. I have shared that link here

https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/3520

Regards,
Mathan